# restfulなAPIの開発経験があるかを知る具体的な方法を知りたい

Tags: api, rest

**自分がRestfulなAPIを作成経験があるかどうかを確認する方法としてどのような方法・ポイントがあるでしょうか？**
実務でAPI自体は作ったことがありますが、それが「Restfulかどうか」確認する方法が知りたいです。
RestfulでないAPIに対して、Restfulかどうかを確認する方法です。細かい観点ではなく、ざっくりとした観点で構いません。

仮説の一つとして、「GET,POST,PUT,DELETEといったHTTPメソッドで操作するAPIの作成経験」はRestfulなAPIの作成経験として、判断指標の一つといえるのではないか。と思っています。

Comment: 簡単では無さそうですが、原典的な書籍を読んでみてはどうでしょう？ [RESTful Webサービス - Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873113539), [RESTful Webサービス - O'Reilly Japan](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873113531/)

Comment: [一度クローズされた質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69930/19110)を再投稿するのはなるべく避けてください。代わりに質問文を編集することで「再オープン票」を集めてください。ほぼ同じ内容の質問が複数投稿されてしまうと情報が散らばってしまいますし、どちらかの質問に割かれた労力が無に帰してしまいます。クローズされた質問を意図的に再投稿するのは一時的なアカウント凍結の原因にもなりえるので、どうぞご注意ください。

Answer (score 1):

> 実務でAPI自体は作ったことがありますが、それが「Restfulかどうか」確認する方法が知りたいです。

おそらくないでしょう（そもそも自分で作ったものがどのようなものかどうかは細かい仕様を提示していただかないと自分以外はだれも判断がつきません、でも実務で作ったものをそう簡単に細かな仕様を公開することはできないでしょうから、判断基準が知りたいというのもわかります）。

おそらくないと書きましたが、もしかしたらあるかもしれません。

つまり、答えは"ない"かもしれないし"ある"かもしれません。

判断する方法がある場合として考えられるのは、お使いのフレームワークのマニュアルかなにかでそのフレームワーク自身がRESTfulですといっていた場合です。（もしくは自分自身がREST原則に従ったAPIを作ったというのでれば経験があると言えそうですが、このような質問をしているので、そうは言えないということになります）

[Rails のルーティング - Railsガイド](https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0-rails%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88)

上記RailsガイドにはRESTfulでの作り方が載っています。

この場合、ご自身がRailsの作法に乗っかって開発をしていたらRESTfulになっているでしょう（ただし世の中のすべてのエンジニアがRailsのAPI作成をRESTfulであると認めているのかどうか私は知りません。おそらくREST原則に従っているはずですが、もしかしたら誰かが抜け漏れに気づくかもしれませんし、議論しだすかもしれません）。作法に乗っからなかった場合はRESTfulにならない可能性があります。

> 仮説の一つとして、「GET,POST,PUT,DELETEといったHTTPメソッドで操作するAPIの作成経験」はRestfulなAPIの作成経験として、判断指標の一つといえるのではないか。と思っています。

GET,POST,PUT,DELETE を使えばRESTfulと言ってしまう人もいるかもしれないですが、おそらく駄目です。

そもそも RESTfulというのはREST原則に従うものだそうです。[Representational State Transfer - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) の情報になってしまいますが、

- ステートレスなクライアント/サーバプロトコル
- すべての情報（リソース）に適用できる「よく定義された操作」のセット
- リソースを一意に識別する「汎用的な構文」
- アプリケーションの情報と状態遷移の両方を扱うことができる「ハイパーメディアの使用」

上記、原則に従うものが RESTful だそうです。 HTTPメソッドに該当するのは上記原則のうちの"すべての情報（リソース）に適用できる「よく定義された操作」のセット" のところです。
なにもHTTPメソッドに限定してはいなさそうですし、HTTPメソッドに限ったとしても、原則の一部でしかありません。

Railsガイドにたくさん`リソース`という単語が記述してあるとおり、RESTfulを名乗るのであれば、`リソース`という考え方が重要です。
しかし `リソース操作` というものについて議論があるようです。

[Representational State Transfer - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) にも

> しかし実際のところこうしたリソース操作は議論の対象となっている。一部の人々には「リソース」と「表現」とを区別することは観念的すぎるとの意見がある。ただし RDFコミュニティでは、リソースと表現の区別は、一般的に行われている。

と少々ややこしいことが書かれています。

（この段落は余談ですが）さらにいくら `GET,POST,PUT,DELETE` でやろうと頑張ったところで、ブラウザーで使用できるHTMLがいつまでたってもPUTとDELETEをサポートしない状況が続いています。このため、RailsやSpringではちょっとしたハック（？）でPUTやDELETE送信したようなFormを作り出しています。とはいえSpringは最近のバージョンアップでPUTとDELETEを諦めたんじゃないかと私は考えています。諦めたと考える理由は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174232/using-deletemapping-will-cause-a-request-method-post-not-supported-error)や[こちら](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#httphiddenmethodfilter-disabled-by-default)にある通りバージョンアップしたら デフォルトでは、PUTとDELETEを使えなくなったからです。 HTMLではなくて直にAPIを叩く等であればこの問題はないのですけれども、やはりWebの多くを占めるブラウザーは無視できないでしょう。

さてやはり、RESTfulで重要なのは`リソース`です（議論の対象になってしまっているようですが）。
`GET,POST,PUT,DELETE`といったHTTPメソッドはサブ的な位置づけと考えたほうがおそらく良いです（まあこの論法でいくと`リソース`も原則の一部です）。`リソース`を操作するためにHTTPメソッドを使っているので、`リソース`という考え方がなければ成り立たない考え方がRESTfulだと思います。

さいごになりますが、本質問は "GET,POST,PUT,DELETEといったHTTPメソッドで操作するAPI はRESTfulですか？"　であれば、YESかNO（今回であればNO)として答えが決めれらるのでスタックオーバーフローに適した質問になると思います（とはいえ、他の情報によってはRESTfulといえてしまうかもしれないので、まだ適切な質問になりきれていない可能性もあります）。私はHTTPメソッドについてを主に取り上げ、HTTPメソッド**だけ**では、RESTfulとはいえませんと回答した形になります。

Comment: もちろん上記原則はそうですが、ある程度信用のある企業での実務の中でのAPI作成になります。常識的な範疇でHTTPメソッドを使っているAPIとしたらrestfulなAPIなのかと思っています。もちろん上記原則も考慮していないことはないでしょう。

Comment: 例えば、「私が扱っている言語がJavaかどうかどうやったらわかりますか？」と聞かれたら、「OSに依存せずJVMによってどんな環境でも動くように設計されてるプログラミング言語」と言われても、果たして自分のがそれなのかどうか確かめるのは少し難しいので「編集しているファイルの拡張子がJavaとなっていませんか？それならJava言語を扱っています」という方が具体的で分かりやすいです。そういった観点でRestful APIを使っているか確証を持つ方法を確認したいです。

Comment: 個人的な見解でいいですし、誤りを恐れるのであれば、円「○○ならRestfulなAPIである可能性がある」ということを聞きたいです。もしご自身が「RestfulなAPIを作ったことがある」という時、どのポイントを根拠にそうおっしゃるかを聞きたかったです。このプラットフォームでは難しいのかもしれませんね。

Comment: @user40231 さん。まず、**スタックオーバーフローの回答に個人的な見解をいれることはできません**  。これはスタックオーバーフローの運営方針なので、もし個人的な見解が欲しい場合は本サイトは適していません。また、説明したいことと論点がずれてしまうかもしれないですが、拡張子だけではJavaであると判断できません。そして大企業かどうかでRESTfulであるかどうかの判断はできません。Railsはむしろベンチャー等で使われることが多いくらいです。ですので、 判断する方法はおそらくないと書きました。また　スタックオーバーフローの質問は回答が１つに決まるようにするように工夫する必要がありますので、「○○なら可能性がある」もしくは「XXであれば可能性がある」とも列挙することもできません。そして可能性があるという推測で答えることもスタックオーバーフローでは本来できません。

Comment: もちろん揚げ足を取るとそうですが、可能性が高い、一般的には、普通に考えるとと言う言い方をするならどうでしょうか。まぁおそらく解決できなさそうなのでいいです。逆に言えば意見を言う投稿はこのプラットフォームでは不向きなのでしょうね。

Comment: @user40231 さん。上記コメント編集してしまって、入れ違いになってしまって申し訳ありません。上記に足したのですが、可能性があるという推測で答えることもスタックオーバーフローではNGなので、ご了承ください。

Comment: @user40231 さん。一般論としてはWikipediaの内容を提示することで回答で説明したつもりであります。

Comment: 拡張子がJavaなのにJavaではない。というのは気になりましたが。。

Comment: プログラミングは難解な言葉や定義が多く、まずは要点を押さえたい。ざっくりとしたイメージを持ちたい。だから個人的見解を聞きたい。みたいなものはこのプラットフォームでは難しいのでしょう。

Comment: @user40231 さん。hoge.javaというファイルに `echo "AA"` と書いて、 php hoge.java とすれば PHP として実行できます。これはJavaではありません。これぐらい厳密なことがスタックオーバーフローでは要求されると私は考えています。

Comment: @user40231 スタック・オーバーフローにおいて、どのような話題 (=トピック) を扱うかについては、ヘルプの [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) 、および [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) も参考にしてください。

Comment: shingo.nakanishi さんのコメントに補足すると、スタック・オーバーフローでは別にすべての主観的な質問を禁じている訳ではありません。個人の経験に基づく回答であっても、それが「なぜ」「どうやって」に基づく建設的なものは歓迎されます。また、問題の解決方法が複数あることはよくあります。たくさんの解決法が寄せられることもまた、歓迎されています。個人の感想だとか個人の経験のみを聞くようなご質問を避けるような仕組みになっています。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask